# Winsocks Compatability issues

Tags: c++, windows, compatibility

I have a executable that requires ws2_32.dll but requires WS2tcpip.h and only works on Windows 7, doesn't work on XP, haven't tried vista.

This is a serious issue, as you can't run the program without missing DLL files. How can I wrap it all up so I won't have any missing DLL issues? Or compatibility issues at all!

Comment: Which function do you need? ws2_32.dll is on all Windows versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just used LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress to find the functions inside of ws2_32.dll, so your standard dynamic function linking. Simple!

Answer (score 0):

ws2_32.dll is on all Windows since...stone age Windows. If it is using some functions that are only on Windows 7 or Windows Vista, then you will have to recompile/port it back to Windows XP, so that it does not need it.

Comment: I think you mean *bronze age* Windows.  In stone age Windows, winsock wasn't included, you had to install [some third-party TCP stack such as Trumpet Winsock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winsock#Other_implementations)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check the following article: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383745%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Update: you should do something like this where you inlcude Windows dependent headers:

```
// Windows XP
#define WINVER 0x0501
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501
#include <Windows.h>
```

Comment: That's a step in the right direction -- but how would I eliminate such errors as missing or not-registered DLLs? I want my program to work on all Windows, especially the popular XP.